# twitter4j 3.0.3 - update status error 404 - only occurs in production

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I got a weird error when updating twitter status via web application using twitter4j 3.0.3.

My application can successfully update a status when I run it in dev environment. But after I deploy and run the application to production environment, it can't update any status.

The application is supposed to be identical. I'm not sure if there's network issue in my production environment. Or probably do twitter only authorize just one application from one machine (dev) and lock it up for other machines (prod)?

All I know is it gives error messages below:

```
2013-12-04 06:18:39 ERROR TwitterServiceImpl:68 - 404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exists. Also returned when the requested format is not supported by the requested method.
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.40 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - /1.1/statuses/update.json</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>/1.1/statuses/update.json</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.40</h3></body></html>

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b2b52c28 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=10981ab8
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-10981ab8], statusCode=404, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}
```

I've created the application on dev.twitter.com and set the access to "Read, Write and Access direct messages". I also use the Consumer key, Consumer secret, Access token, and Access token secret provided in the application details page.

Here's my code in java:

```
@Override
public void updateStatus(String message) throws BusinessException {
    try {
        ConfigurationBuilder confbuilder  = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        confbuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN)
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY)
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(confbuilder.build()).getInstance();

        Status status = twitter.updateStatus(message);
        logger.info("Successfully updated the status to [" + status.getText() + "].");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
        throw new BusinessException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've entered your keys correctly, that your timestamps are in UTC and within a few minutes of ours..

Comment: Hi bububu, thank you for the answer. But I still don't get it with "your timestamps are in UTC and within a few minutes of ours". My server time is now set to "Wed Dec  4 23:14:02 PST 2013", I've checked with http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=137 and it's already synchronized. And I'm pretty sure with the keys though.